# How to change type of parameter in Expression<Func<IQueryable<TModel>, IIncludableQueryable<TModel, object>>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I need to convert type of my expression:

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<TModelBase>, IIncludableQueryable<TModelBase, object>>>
```

to:

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<TModel>, IIncludableQueryable<TModel, object>>>
```

where:

```
TModel : TModelBase
```

I've already tried Expression.Convert method:

```
var converted = Expression.Convert(_baseExpression, typeof(IIncludableQueryable<TModel, object>));
```

It almost worked, because it returned Expression with new type and new word in body "Convert". I want Expression.Body to look the same as it was before Convert, but with changed type.

Example of returned expression after convert:

```
{x => Convert(x => x.Include(m => m.MaterialBaseSomething).Include(m => m.MaterialBaseGroup), IIncludableQueryable`2)}
```

I've also tried ExpressionVisitor to change params types. And I get this:

```
Expression<Func<IQueryable<TModel>, IIncludableQueryable<TModelBase, object>>>
```

so still I need to change result type.

Comment: You can't reliably do this to an arbitrary expression.  You can change the type of the parameter and know it'll work because the derived type will have access to everything the method uses, but you can't make the return type more derived because you can't be sure the expression provided to you will return that type just because you change the type of the input parameter.

Comment: Another solution would be implementing a visitor so you could go throughout the expression and recreate it by replacing with the new semantic.